# Issue in comparing files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

As i am using Windows 7 64 bit, i installed SVN plugin version 1.8 from the site
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

When i compare any file with latest from repository then the comparison is not shown properly. Please refer the screen shot and suggest if i am missing something. I faced this in eclipse indigo also.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "not shown properly"? The screenshot down't realy show what or how it is comparing

Comment: @bvanvelsen I have added a new screen shot now, the issue is what ever java files i compare even if it has a difference in one line, or multiple differences, it always shows as only one box (encircled). So it is not showing the differences properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue, Actually it was considering white-spaces during comparison by default for all files.

Open Window > Preferences from the menu bar
Select General > Compare/Patch in the left-side tree menu
Check "Ignore white space"
Press Apply, then OK

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the *Syncrhonize Perspective*?

Hit Ctrl+F8 and select it from the list.

If it isnot there, click that *"window with a plus icon"* next to *MyEclipse Java ...*, and select it from the appearing list.

Comment: No, it is not Syncrhonize Perspective, i have added a new comment and screen shot, please have a look.

Comment: I see, this should be an issue in Subclipse, try contacting the developers at the [mailing list](http://subclipse.tigris.org/mailing-list-guidelines.html).